# using lda for face recognition multi class

Tags: classification, face-recognition

I've been reading this article [Face Recognition Using LDA-Base Algorithm](http://www.dsp.toronto.edu/~kostas/Publications2008/pub/34.pdf).

After finding the regularized LDA subspace and projecting my training images to this subspace, how do I test the classifier. I projected also the testing images to same subspace... now what ?

all examples I read are for a binary classification using Bayes. To be more clear, now I want to check if giving a face image to the trained classifier will be recognized.

I found this in Szeliski's book, but I can't understand all these equations.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As you know LDA is an acronym for Linear Discriminant Analysis. it actually projects the learning samples into a subspace where the distance between different classes will be maximized meanwhile the distance between the same class samples will be minimized.

So when you are going to use it for Face Recognition, you must have more than one sample from each person (gallery images). then you perform LDA and get the resulting subspace. After this step you have a subspace where all faces can be projected into it.
for the next step you project (using dot product) the gallery images into this subspace and save them as your gallery templates. these templates will be used later in testing step.
the final step is testing. in this step you have a test face image and want to know who it is. So you should calculate its template by projecting this face image into that subspace. Then you calculate the euclidean distance (or some other distance type) of this test template from all of the gallery templates. the closest gallery template have the same identity as the test image.